# Silverlight TreeView template creaton

Tags: templates, silverlight-4.0, treeview

It seems like Silverlight TreeView shows all child levels if we put appropriate number of hierarchical templates.

Is it true?

For example if I have under database table 100 levels of the items is there some way to show all of them without adding extra template section?

**I mean is there some general template that serves to show unlimited child levels?**

The template below shows 2 levels but in fact under the database I can have 1000 levels.

```
  <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ChildTemplate" >
       <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
     </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildTopics}" 
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759035(v=vs.95).aspx